SIP INVITE to the client having 2 lines of same accounts but different PBXs
INVITE URI is not matching with line1 and line 2 accounts completely (username + proxy). How to handle INVITE now? What is the possible response from the phone?
Behavior expected is to route the call to line1. Can I compare username from Request URI and proxy of "From" header with the line1/line2 account?
INVITE sip:av701@12.15.28.12:13270;transport=udp SIP/2.0 Via: SIP/2.0/UDP 13.51.15.3:5060;branch=z9hG4bK3f92bef1 Max-Forwards: 70 From: sip:+90900@troi.ca; To: sip:av701@12.15.28.12:13270;transport=udp Contact: sip:+90900@13.51.15.3:5060
In IP Phone, Line1 registered as - av701@troi.ca & Line2 registered as - av701@lev.ca

No, you cannot compare like that.
Invite is coming from different proxies here. Registered accounts of lines having different proxies. Invite Request URI should change the proxy in it so that it can route to correct end point.
Am I correct??
